# First post audit test using the answer of a 4 year old user with over 150k reputation

Tags: feature-request, support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Well this isn't at all believable as a *first post*. https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1808747

Going by the comments, [duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37213/duffymo) did in fact write that answer, but this was no way his first post.

I'm not sure if this is a bug on some pre-existing code to prevent users like duffymo being used in *first post* audit tests or if this is simply something which isn't in place at all.

If it is a bug: hey, this is a bug report!

If it isn't: maybe something should be put in place to prevent *old* users being used in first post reviews like this.

Comment: Or maybe just display 1 reputation instead of the user's actual score?

Comment: The audit selector doesn't select first posts, it selects *bad* posts that will stick out. The criteria is deleted by moderator due to flag (in the most basic summary). The point is for you to catch the *content* as bad, so the user shouldn't matter. In fact, I think the user makes this one harder because it'll catch those people who go "oh, 150k, Looks Good" and get slammed with a "Review Audit Failed."

Comment: The aim of the Review Audit is to simply detect Robo Reviewers. So, if a person does pay attention to observe the Rep and process that, I think that Reviewer is *doing* fine (and will flag it). On the other hand, a click through reviewer will probably fail irrespective of the information at hand.

Comment: the aim of this audit is pretty philosophical. It kind of tells the attentive reader, _"hey we all were first time users once upon a time, we all wrote crappy answers. Work hard, learn how to answer and maybe one day you'll become a veteran with hundreds thousands rep"_ I would want to believe this is **[meta-tag:status-by-design]**

Comment: @gnat It's not really believable that a user with a first answer posted on March 18th 2013 would be a user with 150k reputation just 10 days later. The problem is that the reputation and badge counts stick out like a sore thumb here.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I know I know. but... I just want to believe that this makes a slightest sense. I want to believe it so much that I am even inventing an explanation for this... (hush hush I didn't tell you) blatantly crappy test design that jeopardizes the purpose of [meta-tag:review-audits]. "designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills", gimme a break

Comment: Devil's advocate: robo-reviewers won't give a crap.

Comment: Off-topic: it's hard to believe a 150k+ user would post [such an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478899/array-is-printing-null/15478993#15478993) and after it gets deleted [posts another "answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15479477/502381) that is promptly deleted. But there it is.